# Update DownloadManager.Request

Tags: android, android-download-manager

**Use case:**
user is downloading a file over wifi and loses connection. If the device switches over to mobile network, the user should give permission to continue downloading over a mobile network.

**Question:**
Is it possible to update the `DownloadManager.Request` and call `setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);` on it, so it can continue downloading over the mobile network without starting a new download?